# Can I concatenate a virtual column in a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

Unfortunately, I have plaintext passwords in a database.  I want to pass these plaintext values around as little as possible for, say, comparisons and updates.  To this end, I'm trying to create a view of my Users table that excludes the plaintext passwords and instead provides a hashed value of that password.

Here's my current SQL Server view, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(32768 * RAND() AS INT) AS NVARCHAR) AS PasswordSalt
       HashBytes('SHA1', PasswordSalt + u.Password) AS PasswordHash
FROM dbo.Users AS u
```

I'd be happy to hear about alternatives to this approach, but otherwise the problem seems to be concatenating the virtual column **PasswordSalt** with.. anything.  For instance, the following simple view works:

```
SELECT u.Login AS Column1, u.Login + 'b' AS Column2
```

but this one does not:

```
SELECT u.Login AS Column1, Column1 + 'b' AS Column2
```

The error I'm receiving from Management Studio is

> Invalid column name 'Column1'.

Thanks in advance for any ideas about what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: You could just encrypt the column (SQL Server 2005+): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Only way I could reproduce the error was because the column1 didn't exist

Comment: I chose a hash to ensure the transform is reproducible by consumers without their being able to recover `u.Password`.  I believe that rules out encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because the FROM clause of your statement indicates that the data to be selected comes from the Users table, but the SELECT part references a column named PasswordSalt. SQL Server cannot find a column with this name on the Users table, hence the error.

Alternative approach may be to generate the Salt in a subquery. For example

`SELECT x.PasswordSalt, 
       HashBytes('SHA1', x.PasswordSalt + x.Password) AS PasswordHash
FROM ( SELECT  CAST(CAST(32768 * RAND() AS INT) AS NVARCHAR) AS PasswordSalt, 
       Password 
       FROM dbo.Users) x`

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(32768 * RAND() AS INT) AS NVARCHAR) AS PasswordSalt 
       HashBytes('SHA1', CAST(CAST(32768 * RAND() AS INT) AS NVARCHAR) + u.Password) AS PasswordHash 
FROM dbo.Users AS u
```

Comment: This one seems problematic because I need to ensure that the *PasswordSalt* virtual column contains the same value that is hashed with the password.  If they ever differ, consumers won't be able to verify the passwords match.

Comment: I believe that no matter how many times you call Rand() it will return same value for each row in the set